# TFS 2013 BuildService stuck

Tags: service, tfs, build

Since 2 days we have a really big issue on our TFS system.
After the build agent activity the build stay stuck undefinitely.

We have detected that the issue is linked to the NotifyBuildCompleted action in the closure part of the build event.

A timeout occured each time this part of the build process is reached.

At the end the build agent is available but the build controler is still busy with the closure  and will not see anymore the agent as available.

On the Build overview panel I can see the build is still "In Process" and also it's in the completed tab . The duration, completed date and execution time have bad values. In the database the tbl_buildqueued stay with the build status 1 instead of the closed status.

We have CI build since 1 month and it's the first time we have this kind of issue.

Did someone have a solution or an idea to solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you restarted the controller, both the service and the machine physically? is there a network issue between the TFS server and the Build controller? can you provide the log information?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted controler/agents/TFS/ the VM/ IIS recycle. I also have delete this controler and recreate another one but result is the same.  If i call the Build/V3.0/BuildService.asmx service who is responsible of this issue I receive a timeout exception using SoapUi, but for other services on this WSDL it's working (query build qualities by example). it's like the NotifyBuildCompleted method can't perform some actions .

Comment: I have fount the following error in the event log, do you think it can be linked ? : The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppStateQueryJobDefinition (ID c5eb369d-264c-4478-9ab3-7eb9540dc065) threw an exception. More information is included below.

Sorry, we can't seem to connect to the SharePoint Store. Try again in a bit.

Comment: That looks like a sharepoint, rather than tfs error, it may be related if a dns name can't be resolved, but i would err on saying no. is sharepoint installed on the same server?

Comment: is there anything showing in the TFS event log. Applications and Services log > Microsoft - Team Foundation Server? is the TFSJobagent running ok?

Comment: or in the diagnostics at http://TFSSERVER:8080/tfs/_oi/

Comment: Yes TFS and Sharepoint are on the same server.  In the event log I have some issues but I can't make a link with our error. It's probably side effect about the real error : TF14045: The identity with type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity' and identifier 'S-1-5-21-1328236037-1172046531-623648099-4059' could not be found.  IP Address: ::1 Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): TF14045: The identity with type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity' and identifier 'S-1-5-21-1328236037-1172046531-623648099-4059' could not be found.

Comment: TFS job agent is running. I think something on our infrastructure has changed and the security rules around the Sharepoint and TFS is not the same. The TFSReport user is used to query the difusion list for build notification on sharepoint but it's impossible to this user to receive a response from the Sharepoint service. All the build activity on the build agent is correct on the logs and (we have the log info workflow completed)

Comment: We have a lot of error with Sharepoint COM server component and the error linked befor (connect to Sharepoint) , all the time the error is related to TFSReport user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of search and contact with microsoft it's something linked to the stored procedure.

To avoid this build stuck we add 1 GO memory on our SQL server .

Now build are correctly stoped / finished by the NotificationCompleted event.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Run the BPA which can be downloaded from [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) and see if there are any issues with the accounts that are used for TFS, particularly the SQL and sharepoint accounts

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will try that monday and keep you informed.

Comment: I have run the analysis and no problems where founded linked to this collection. By checking again the event logs I found this recurent error :

Comment: The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{61738644-F196-11D0-9953-00C04FD919C1}
 and APPID 
{61738644-F196-11D0-9953-00C04FD919C1}
 to the user ******\TFSReports SID (S-1-5-21-1328236037-1172046531-623648099-10543) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: Default Controller - *****tfs401: Failed to finalize build vstfs:///Build/Build/1413 due to an exception.
Exception Type: System.TimeoutException
Exception Message: The http request operation timed out after 00:15:00.
Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRetryChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
   at

Comment: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildWebService4.NotifyBuildCompleted(Uri buildUri)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildDetail.FinalizeStatus()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.FlushBuild(IBuildDetail build, BuildStatus finalStatus)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.OnInstanceCompleted(BuildWorkflowInstance instance, IDictionary`2 outputs, Exception terminationException)

Comment: After extra investigation we try to execute a build on another team project collection and it'(s working. Any idea what can stuck a teamcollection for NotiFibuildcompleted event ?

Comment: So you've disconnected the controller from the TPC and then connected it to another TPC, ran a build and it worked ok?

Comment: Yes, I think something wrong is still stuck in the tfs_collection database, because same buildcontroler configured on the other tfs collection was working.

Comment: sounds very weird, do you have much in that TPC?

Comment: Around 10 team projects and a lot of code. The other collection where we test the build is a copy of this collection (used as a sandbox)

Comment: 2 collections are identical. We have one sandbox wich is an image of 3 month ago